# Modify specific cell in Python CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am writing a vending machine simulation in Python as school work and I am required to edit a specific line to keep a stock list up to date.

Here is the code:

```
import csv

with open('stock.csv','r') as STOCK_READ: #Counts the amount of items in the CSV file
    ITEM_COUNT = 0
    reader = csv.reader(STOCK_READ)
    for line in reader:
        ITEM_COUNT = ITEM_COUNT + 1

def GET_STOCK_COUNT():
    with open('stock.csv', 'r') as STOCK_READ:
        reader = csv.reader(STOCK_READ)
        for line in reader:
            print("{0} - {1} - {2} in stock".format(line[0],line[1],line[2]))

while True:
    GET_STOCK_COUNT()
    CHOSEN_ITEM = int(input("Input number of desired item: "))
```

Here is the CSV (It goes: Item no., Name, Stock):

```
1,Coca Cola,10
2,Monster,10
3,Monster Ultra,10
```

By making the user select the number, I want to make the CSV writer go to the correct line and make the change to the number at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on a good path. You need a function to update your file in the same way you read it. I have written such a function for example. Here you go:

```
import csv

with open('stock.csv','r') as STOCK_READ: #Counts the amount of items in the CSV file
    ITEM_COUNT = 0
    reader = csv.reader(STOCK_READ)
    for line in reader:
        ITEM_COUNT = ITEM_COUNT + 1

def GET_STOCK_COUNT():
    with open('stock.csv', 'r') as STOCK_READ:
        reader = csv.reader(STOCK_READ)
        for line in reader:
            print("{0} - {1} - {2} in stock".format(line[0],line[1],line[2]))

def UPDATE_STOCK_COUNT(item_id):
    with open('stock.csv', 'r') as STOCK_READ:
        reader = csv.reader(STOCK_READ)
        output = []
        for line in reader:
            if line[0] == item_id:
                line[2] = str(int(line[2])-1)
            output.append(line)
    with open('stock.csv', 'w', newline='') as STOCK_WRITE:
        writer = csv.writer(STOCK_WRITE)
        writer.writerows(output)

while True:
    GET_STOCK_COUNT()
    CHOSEN_ITEM = input("Input number of desired item: ")
    UPDATE_STOCK_COUNT(CHOSEN_ITEM)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good place to use a dictionary. If in your GET_STOCK_COUNT function you saved the data to a dictionary and then return the dictionary you will be able to access and then modify the data as you want.

```
def GET_STOCK_COUNT():
    stock = {}
    with open('stock.csv', 'r') as STOCK_READ:
        reader = csv.reader(STOCK_READ)
        for line in reader:
            stock[line[0]] = {
                'name': line[1],
                'stock': line[2],
            }

    return stock
```

This will allow you to then reference an item by the stock index number.
For example if you wanted to change the the stock for a line item you could then do something like this:

```
stock = GET_STOCK_COUNT()
stock[CHOSEN_ITEM]['stock'] = new_value
```

You will need to write a new function to print your stock list but you now have the data accessible so this is still possible.